# Get folder tag recognised by Automator within Photos library file

Tags: finder, automator, photos.app, finder-tag

I am trying to back my entire Photos library to OneDrive, following this early 2016 tutorial: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/share-pictures-OSX-photos-app-OneDrive/

When I step through the "*Find finder Items*" step in Automator however, it executes the step, but does not find any files or folders tagged as blue. These are not shown underneath the button "Results" either.

My suspicion this has something to do with the step where you have to right click on the library file and select "*Show Package Contents*", and that Automator now ignores any subfolders in this file.

The tagged "*Master*" folder **can** be found by filtering by blue tag in Finder.

I could not find anything on getting folder tags visible within these "*packages*"/library files.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Select everything you want inside the package, ⌘+C and ⌘+option+V somewhere else. Adapt your search for the new path. So the files/folders won't be "hidden" inside the package.